# Syslinux EFI 64bit: start_image() returned Load Error

Tags: linux, compilation, x86-64, uefi, syslinux

The syslinux binaries provided by debian are working well with qemu.

But I have compiled syslinux from Debian 12 source code. And when I run it with qemu, it fails saying `start_image() returned Load Error`.

I first installed the packages needed to the build:

```bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev make python-is-python3 nasm uuid-dev gnu-efi
```

Then I downloaded the source code of syslinux:

```bash
mkdir ./Desktop/syslinux-mod
cd ./Desktop/syslinux-mod
apt-get source syslinux
```

To avoid a compilation error, in the file `./syslinux-6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1/efi/efi.h` I have replaced lines 23, 24, 25:

```
#include <efi.h>
#include <efilib.h>
#include <efistdarg.h>
```

by:

```
#include <efi/efi.h>
#include <efi/efilib.h>
#include <efi/efistdarg.h>
#include <efi/efisetjmp.h>
```

Then I compiled with the command `make efi64`

I have created a virtual machine drive file, a gpt partition table, and a boot partition.

Once the boot partition mounted, I have copied to it in the directory `/EFI/boot/`:

- all `.c32` files found in `./syslinux-6.04~git20190206.bf6db5b4+dfsg1/efi64` subdirectories
- ldlinux.e64
- syslinux.efi, renamed grubx64.efi, because I use the bootx64.efi from the debian live DVD, that want to chainload to grubx64.efi.

About qemu, I installed:

```bash
sudo apt-get install qemu-system-x86 aqemu ovmf
```

Then I have configured `aqemu`, a graphical frontend to qemu, to use `TCG` accelerator instead of `KVM`. And a command line parameter `-bios /usr/share/ovmf/OVMF.fd`.

When I try to rename `syslinux.efi` directly `bootx64.efi`, qemu display another error message, but I didn't have the time to read it.

So I wonder how to get a syslinux working installation from the source code provided by Debian.